# PHP web scraping WITH curl

Tags: php, web-scraping, curl

I try to scrape on the https://www.ktown4u.com/searchList?goodsTextSearch=aespa&grp_no=1723449
want to get the p tag, but it return me 'No results' and 'GOODS_NM' that's from it js function,
how can i get the content ?
ex.aespa - The 3rd Mini Album [MY WORLD] (Poster Ver.) (GISELLE) (U.S.A Version)

this my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $search = $_POST['search'];
            $url = "https://www.ktown4u.com/searchList?goodsTextSearch=".$search."&grp_no=1723449";
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $html = curl_exec($ch);
            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            @ $dom->loadHTML($html);
            $ps = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
            $ps_array = array();
            foreach($ps as $p){
                $title_text = $p->textContent;
                $ps_array[] = $title_text;
                echo $title_text . '<br>';
            }
        }
```

result:

```
aespa
No results
Please try other keywords or please check the spacing.
No results
Please try other keywords or please check the spacing.
How about this kind of product?
0
0
Category
BROWSING HISTORY
How about this kind of product?
{{GOODS_NM}}
Company name: Ktown4u Co.,Ltd. CEO: Song Hyo Min
Business Registration Number: 120-87-71116
CS Centre: CS Talk
Affiliate Enquiry: Ktown4u@ktown4u.com
Office Address: 513, Yeongdong-daero, Gangnam-gu, Seoul, Republic of Korea
Distribution Centre: No.49, Floor 9, 55, Bukhang-ro 120beon-gil, Seo-gu, Incheon, Republic of Korea (22853)
Copyright ⓒ All rights reserved. Ktown4u.com
```

Comment: From a brief glance at the page (and looking at the View Source feature, and the Developer Tools when the page is loaded into a browser), I think it's because the actual searching is done via subsequent AJAX requests to the backend, not by the initial request. And of course when you fetch the data via curl, there is no browser environment in which to execute the JavaScript and initiate the AJAX request, so the search doesn't happen.

Comment: Scraping without a JavaScript engine running will fail for most modern websites, since some of the page generation happens after the initial fetch  The static page you fetch is just a skeleton that is fleshed out with frames and scripting.  To see this, open F12 tools in Google Chrome and go to a page.  See all the extra fetches beyond the page itself.